# Implementation AES CM in SRTP at linphone

Tags: encryption, aes, voip, linphone

I tried to understand how the implementation of srtp on the linphone application. When I activate the srtp feature on the phone, the digital data communication will be secured using the AES-ICM encryption method. But I found something interesting in its implementation.

The encryption process in the AES-ICM method works with xor operations between keystream suffix and RTP packet payload (plaintext) to produce ciphertext. The encryption key is used in an aes operation to generate a suffix keystream. This ciphertext will then be sent from the sender to the receiver.

In the implementation of SRTP, I display the plaintext, key and ciphertext used or generated by the sender and receiver. I found the difference between the ciphertext and key for each packet in the sender and receiver. When a plaintext is encrypted using a specific key and produces a ciphertext in the sender, the receiver, the ciphertext that is received and the key that is used has a difference. However, the strange thing that I found was that the results of the decryption of the plaintext on the receiver are the same plaintext as what is encrypted in the sender. And the voice that was communicated arrived, can anyone explain this why?

Code to display text : https://pastelink.net/1re6m

Log endpoint 1 : https://pastelink.net/1re93

Log endpoint 2 : https://pastelink.net/1re9c

Then, I tried to deactivate the encryption feature by using the srtp_cipher_encrypt code in the srtp_protect_mki and srtp_cipher_decrypt modules in the srtp_unprotect_mki module. Isn't that as if it didn't encrypt the payload like the Null Cipher is implemented? However, the same ones found are ciphertext and plaintext that have nothing in common with the sender and receiver as well as the sound on the speakers that contain noise without being able to identify what is being sent. Can anyone explain this too?

For example, the first plaintext used for encryption at endpoint one is:
"d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d ......"
generate ciphertext:
"7c8fb6c2f783e5fdb34116bb5d5ce27475bf400b4 ........"

then at endpoint 2 which acts as a receiver, the first ciphertext received is
"e2bd90a5275e44ac2d4fc332cfff138e743c39c80b ......."
generate plaintext:
"d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5d5 ......."

Thank you

Comment: I really can't figure out what you're asking, and the links don't help. You state: *...the strange thing that I found was that the results of the decryption of the plaintext on the receiver are the same plaintext as what is encrypted in the sender...* and that's how encryption and decryption are **supposed** to work. It wouldn't be any good if decryption didn't give you back the original plaintext.

Comment: Thank for your response. 
Yes, the plaintext must be the same on the sender and receiver in the encryption mechanism. 
Put simply, what I want to ask is why are the ciphertext in the sender and receiver different for the same plaintext?
What I mean by link is to show ciphertext and plaintext which are two different endpoints (sender and receiver). In both files you can find the same plaintext but different ciphertext.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer from another forum. In my case this is happening because the VOIP server which is I am using Asterisk will decrypt every incoming packet for processing before sending it back. This package will then be re-encrypted by Asterisk before being sent to its final destination. Every packet that enters will be decrypted and the one that exits the asterisk will be re-encrypted. So, in my case, this happened because of the voip server technology used.